# Encontrar padrões dentro de uma String

Tags: java, string, regex

Estou com dificuldades para encontrar dois padrões dentro de uma string em java, dado uma string. Por exemplo:

```
String str = 021478345231402198408189472328090419790164437663021101996091789834401805198616773422110231220010017325545008091968040901876902511198100789089990090919991753135151210101987;
```

Eu sei que a cada 11 dígitos é um cpf e a cada 8 digitos após o cpf é uma data de nascimento.

Preciso resolver essa questão

> 1. Dado um arquivo sequencial, com registros de tamanho fixo, contendo números de CPF (11 bytes) seguidos de datas de nascimento (8 bytes).
>
> Identifique:
>
> Quantos registros existem no arquivo? Qual a posição do 3º registro?
>   (Crie uma formula) Liste um registro por linha e separando os campos
>   por `,`

posso usar o pattern para localizar x numeros, mas não compreendi para achar x e y padrão.

tentei fazer usando uma `substring(0,9)+",";` mas ele trocou o ultimo numero pelo `,`.

Comment: Isso daí é um exercício de faculdade ou algo assim?

Comment: isso, estruturas de dados, precisávamos de uma luz, conseguimos fazer algumas coisas, mas nao localizar certa como pede. adicionando o , conseguimos quebrar ela usando o split();

Comment: Cada linha do arquivo tem 19 caracteres é isso?

Comment: Crie uma classe que representa o registro. 11+8=19. Assim sendo, crie um `for` que separe essa string em partes a cada 19 caracteres. Para cada parte de 19 caracteres, você separa os 11 primeiros do CPF dos 8 últimos da data e os usa para criar uma instância do seu registro e produz então uma lista com esses registros. Sobreescreva o método `toString` dessa classe colocando o resultado separado por vírgula. Por fim, você itera a lista produzida e dá um `System.out.println` em cada item.

Comment: então, isso ali é uma linha unica um Str unico, preciso quebrar ele e achar os cpf e rg por exemplo, 02147834523,14021984,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser feito criando um List e uma classe pojo com duas Strings cpf e nascimento

```
//Variaveis preliminares
    List<Pessoa> todos = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
    String str = "021478345231402198408189472328090419790164437663021101996091789834401805198616773422110231220010017325545008091968040901876902511198100789089990090919991753135151210101987";
    int ncaracteres = str.length();
    int npessoas = ncaracteres / 19;
    String cpf,nascimento;

    //Produz a separação dos termos em uma List do tipo Pessoa e suas variáveis cpf e nascimento
    for (int i=0;i<npessoas;i++){
        int c = i * 19;
        cpf=str.substring(c+0,c+11);
        nascimento=str.substring(c+11,c+19);
        todos.add(new Pessoa(cpf,nascimento));
        System.out.println("CPF: "+cpf +" , "+"NASCIMENTO: "+nascimento);
    }

    //Uso dos dados conforme desejado,
    //lembrando que a posição de .get(x) para obter a 3 posição insere 2 pois o 0 conta como primeiro item
    System.out.println("Número de registros: "+todos.size());
    System.out.println("Dados 3 registro: "+todos.get(2).getCpf() + " NASCIMENTO: "+todos.get(2).getNascimento() );

public class Pessoa{
    String cpf;
    String nascimento;
    public Pessoa(String cpf, String nascimento) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.nascimento = nascimento;
    }
    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }
    public String getNascimento() {
        return nascimento;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Segue um exemplo de como separar a String em caracteres para você conseguir fazer o exercício. Com esse exemplo você consegue separar as datas também.

```
//Nesse exemplo só vou dividir os números a cada 11 números
   String str = "021478345231402198408189472328090419790164437663021101996091789834401805198616773422110231220010017325545008091968040901876902511198100789089990090919991753135151210101987"; 
     int b=1;
     String g = "";
        for (int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++) {
            //aqui é pego cada caracter da String
            String c = String.valueOf( str.charAt(a));
            //concatena uma nova string com os dados achados
            g = g + c;
            b++;

            //a cada 11 caracters é feita a impressão                      
            if (b > 11) {
            //Caso você queira salvar os dados correspondentes a cpf ou data
            //Você pode criar uma lista e adicionar os dados ja concatenado
            System.out.println("Disão a cada 11 números " + g);

                //iniciar e continuar o próximo loop do for
                 b = 1;
                 g="";
            }
    }
```